# Make 2D pixel plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, grid, pixel

I have the following data:

```
Latitude, Longitude, U component of wind
```

Where Latitude and Longitude are the coordinates and U component of wind is the speed of wind in m/s. Each (Latitude, Longitude, U component of wind) pair/pixel covers 50000 meter (50km) on ground (on plot). There are 364 points (pairs) and rest of the rectangular area can have white space.

I would like to prepare kind of a 2D plot with matplotlib, where each pixel gets a colour (rainbow colors going from red to violet, from the min to the max values of the U component of wind column) according to the value of the 3rd column, and data is read from CSV file. I wonder what is the best approach for this with matplotlib?

Edit CSV File: [CSV File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xmVuPfPjijHGFKLQlQR3V3OZ1-1wHMqZ/view?usp=sharing)
[Image from CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xuTu.png)

Comment: ① a pixel maps to an area, not to a length ② wind has velocity but also a direction ③ whatever you want to draw, you want to draw it on a geographical map? Please clarify these issues ([edit]ing your question) if you don't want that SO closes your question.

Comment: 2) I have edited the question, it is U component of the wind so no directions required. 3) Not on a geographical map but on a bounding box-like 2d plot.

Comment: Please see the [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/index.html) and create a [minimal, reproducible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In the CSV you've linked, the normalized U component ranges, approximately, from 25 (what?) to 35 (what?). In the drawing that you've posted, the colorbar shows that U ranges from -2 to 3. What are you doing? Why? ——

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

# this part is about faking data
x = y =np.linspace(0, 1200, 24, endpoint=0)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
positions = np.arange(24*24, dtype=int)

np.random.seed(2013-3-9)
np.random.shuffle(positions)
points = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(
    X.flatten()[positions[:364]], Y.flatten()[positions[:364]])]
velocities = np.random.rand(364)+(X+Y).flatten()[positions[:364]]/1000

with open('wind.csv', 'w') as out:
    for p, v in zip(points, velocities):
        print(*p, v, sep=',', file=out)

# start reading here
# read from CSV
with open('wind.csv') as inp:
    points, velocities = [], []
    for line in inp:
        x, y, v = (float(value) for value in line.split(','))
        points.append((x, y)), velocities.append(v)
 
pc = PatchCollection([plt.Rectangle(point, 50, 50) for point in points],
                     norm=plt.Normalize(), cmap='rainbow_r')
pc.set_array(velocities)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,6), layout='constrained')
ax.set_aspect(1)
rectangles = ax.add_collection(pc)
ax.autoscale()
cb = fig.colorbar(rectangles)
cb.set_label('Normalized Wind Velocity', size='large')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your approach but the resultant image is a bit off. I have attached/edited the link to image and csv file in the post.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

# read  CSV, split lines, convert to floats, transpose. convert to arrays
lats, lons, velocities = (
    np.array(lis) for lis in zip(*[
        [float(yxw) for yxw in line.split(',')]
        for line in open('windU.csv')])
        )

# the projections we use, Lambert for the map, PlateCarree auxiliary
proj = ccrs.LambertAzimuthalEqualArea(68.5, 0.5) # centred on map area
pc = ccrs.PlateCarree()

# from coordinates in PlateCarree to map coordinates (in metre from centre)
x, y, z = proj.transform_points(pc, lons, lats).T

# Rectangle has sides starting in (point), so to have centered Rectangles...
points = zip(*[x-25000, y-25000])

# create a PatchCollection from a list of Rectangles
collection = PatchCollection(
    [plt.Rectangle(point, 50000, 50000) for point in points],
    norm=plt.Normalize(), cmap='rainbow_r', alpha=0.5)

# we want the squares according to the normalized velocities
collection.set_array(velocities)

# usual stuff, except the ax projection is LambertAzimuthalEqualArea
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,3), layout='constrained')
ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)

ax.stock_img() # here it simply draws the Indian Ocean
ax.set_extent((61, 76, -3, 4))

squares = ax.add_collection(collection)

# this is removable, just to check that squares are centred correctly
ax.scatter(x, y, s=0.3, c='w')

# add the colorbar, customize it
cb = plt.colorbar(squares)
cb.set_label('Normalized Wind Velocity\n(U component)', size='large')

# eventually, draw the coastlines — here the archipelago of the Maldives
ax.coastlines(lw=1.5)
# and the axis labels
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I was really bored